# Azure Build Pipeline Not Mapping Files to Docker Volume

Tags: bash, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, liquibase

I am in the process of creating our Azure DevOps Continuous Deployment pipeline.

One of the steps is to apply a database migration to our environment via scripts from source control. I'm leveraging Docker to avoid needing to install the migration tool (Liquibase) on the agent:

```yaml
- stage: "ReleaseDev"    
    jobs:
      - deployment: "Database Migration (Development)"
        pool:
          name: "Some Servers"
        environment: "Development - Some Environment"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - bash: |
                  docker run --rm -v "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/db/Internal:/liquibase/changelog" liquibase/liquibase --url="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.company.com;Database=SomeTestDatabase;" --changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/liquibaseChangeLog.json --username=dbo_liquibase --password=$DEV_LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD update                  
        env:
          DEV_LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD: $(dev-liquibase-password)
```

However, it doesn't appear to be finding the `liquibaseChangeLog.json` file from the mapped volume in the container:

```sh
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[debug]which '/bin/bash'
##[debug]found: '/bin/bash'
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: --noprofile
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: --norc
##[debug]/bin/bash arg: /home/azure/azure1/agent/_work/_temp/b865f905-04d6-4f31-8c9b-74a312d47670.sh
##[debug]exec tool: /bin/bash
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   --noprofile
##[debug]   --norc
##[debug]   /home/azure/azure1/agent/_work/_temp/b865f905-04d6-4f31-8c9b-74a312d47670.sh
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/azure/azure1/agent/_work/_temp/b865f905-04d6-4f31-8c9b-74a312d47670.sh
Liquibase Community 3.8.9 by Datical
Unexpected error running Liquibase: /liquibase/changelog/liquibaseChangeLog.json does not exist
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

##[debug]Exit code 255 received from tool '/bin/bash'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/bin/bash'
##[error]Bash exited with code '255'.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Bash exited with code '255'.
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;done=true;]
Finishing: Bash
```

I've done a very similar thing in our CI pipeline for branches but the script executed within a Docker-Compose task and not a standalone bash script. So I'm confused what's different in this case.

Looking for some advice for a poor windows developer :)

**EDIT:** After Leo's suggestion below, it enabled me to come up with this as a final working solution. His comments are the principle, this is the practice.

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: "BuildJob"
        variables:
          solution: "**/*.sln"
          buildPlatform: "any cpu"
          buildConfiguration: "Release"
        pool:
          name: "xxx Build Servers"
        steps:          
          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: "Publish Pipeline Artifact - DB Migrations"
            inputs:
              targetPath: "db"
              artifact: "db_migrations"
  - stage: "ReleaseDev"    
    jobs:
      - deployment: "Development_DbMigration"
        pool:
          name: "xxx Docker Hosts"
        environment: "Development - Web Farm"
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                  displayName: "Download Pipeline Artifact - DB Migrations"
                  inputs:
                   artifactName: 'db_migrations'
                   targetPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/db'
                - bash: |                                                        
                    docker run --rm -v "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/db/Internal:/liquibase/changelog" liquibase/liquibase --url="jdbc:sqlserver://dev.xxx.com;Database=SomeDatabase;" --changeLogFile=/liquibase/changelog/liquibaseChangeLog.json --username=dbo_SomeDatabase --password=$DEV_LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD update                    
                  env:
                    DEV_LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD: $(dev-liquibase-password)
```

Comment: I still haven't gotten it but it appears that my directory of source items (`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`) is empty. That's because this is a release pipeline and I guess its empty here?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: It definitely got me on the right track! I am putting together my more specific answer which ended up working. I’m having to sanitize the solution a bit so it doesn’t contain company details and it only has the tasks that pertain to the issue

Comment: @Killnine yes if you've configured a deployment stage (as ReleaseDev is), it won't do a `checkout` task first whch it does inherently in the normal jobs. You can just add it yourself `- checkout: self` iirc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Build Pipeline Not Mapping Files to Docker Volume

Your comment is critical, and you are very close to your answer based on your comment.

If you are only add the - stage: "ReleaseDev" in your release pipeline, you will get that issue.

In order to support Release pipelines (CD) in YAML as well, MS offer a unified YAML experience, so you can configure each of your pipelines to do CI, CD, or CI and CD together.

Besides, MS also provides different built-in tasks for build/deployment, like `Checkout` for `build` stage, `Download Artifact` for deployment stage.

So, if we only add the `ReleaseDev` in the pipeline without `build` stage, it will missing the built-in task `Checkout`. That the reason why the directory `$(Build.SourcesDirectory` is empty:

[image]

To resolve this issue, we just need to a stage build with a simple task:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
     name: MyPrivateAgent
    steps:
       - script: |
          echo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

- stage: "ReleaseDev"    
    jobs:
      - deployment: "Database Migration (Development)"
        pool:
          name: "Some Servers"
```

Now, we could get the source code from the repo:

[image]

Note: If you have multiple agents in parallel, you may also need to pay attention to whether the build and deploy are running on the same agent, if not, we need to manually upload and download them, check [this document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-artifacts.md) for some more details.

Hope this helps.